# Running multiple test cases in Selenium TestNG XML

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to automate a scenario wherein, I want to Login once into the application & then do manipulations without having to re-login again.

Consider that, I have the created a base class which contains `@BeforeSuite`, `@BeforeTest`, etc.. all methods include a driver setup and all in a specific class.

Then I have 3 Java files containing multiple test cases in each..

```
public class firstJavaClass extends TestBase {

  List<WebElement> elementList;
  WebElement e;

  @Test(priority = 0, enabled=true)
  public void firstTest() {
    new Login(driver, "user");

    driver.get(baseURL);
    implicitWait();
  }

  @Test(priority = 1, enabled=true)
  public void secondTest() {
    for(WebElement e : elementList)
      Helper.getValue(e);
    }
  }
```

I am using **TestNG** to run all these tests in a combined suite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite">
    <test name="TEST">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.automation.firstJavaClass />
            <class name="com.automation.secondJavaClass />
            <class name="com.automation.thirdJavaClass />
            <class name="com.automation.secondJavaClass />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The error I am getting is it executes only first test from the `firstJavaClass` and then execute the first test from `secondJavaClass` and then it's failed by throwing `NullPointerException`.

I am not sure if I am doing mistake in writing `XML`  or any other error. Because if I am running any java classes as a `TestNG test`, then it's executing perfectly. Please suggest how can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

this is secondJavaClass

```
public class secondJavaClass extends TestBase {  

List<WebElement> elementList; WebElement e; 

@Test(priority = 0, enabled=true) 
public void pageTitleMain() { 
Helper.getCss(Profiles.getPageTitle(driver)); 
} 

@Test(priority = 1, enabled=true) 
public void pageTitleSub() {
 Helper.getCss(Profiles.getPageNameTitle(driver)); 
} 

@Test(priority = 2, enabled=true) public void unselectedSubNavMenu() 
{ 
elementList = Profiles.subNavUnSelected(driver); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Why do you have secondJavaClass two times in testng.xml ? and share the code for secondJavaClass  , since you have mentioned  `then execute first test from secondJavaClass and then it's failed by throwing NullPointerException`

Comment: I have common test cases in `secondJavaClass` for both `firstJavaClass` and `thirdJavaClass`

`public class secondJavaClass extends TestBase {
 
 List<WebElement> elementList;
 WebElement e;
 
 @Test(priority = 0, enabled=true)
 public void pageTitleMain() {
  Helper.getCss(Profiles.getPageTitle(driver));
 }
 @Test(priority = 1, enabled=true)
 public void pageTitleSub() {
  Helper.getCss(Profiles.getPageNameTitle(driver));
 }

 @Test(priority = 2, enabled=true)
 public void unselectedSubNavMenu() {
  elementList = Profiles.subNavUnSelected(driver);
 }
}`

Comment: Why are you invoking `<class name="com.automation.secondJavaClass />` two times in TestNG.xml file?

Comment: Whether do you have any After Test/class Method?. I suspect, driver value becomes null and after executing the pageTitleMain method.

Comment: 1) First of all this issue is not related to testng.xml. 2)If you write one class as two times it will be executed one time only (Second Class) 3) PLease share the code of Helper class

Comment: @automateThings 1) What should be the issue? 2) How can I achieve this? It's not working even if I am executing second class only one time. 3) `public class Helper {

 private WebDriver driver;
 private Logger log = LoggerHelper.getLogger(Helper.class);

 public CSSHelper(WebDriver driver) {
  this.driver = driver;
  log.info("CSSHelper object has been craeted..");
 }

 public static void getCss(WebElement e) {
  TestBase.logReport(e.getCssValue("font-family");
 }

 public static void getValue(WebElement e) {
  
  TestBase.logReport(e.getCssValue("font-family");
 }
}`

Comment: @Subburaj No, I have quit driver method in `@AfterSuite`, I am just capturing screenshot in `@AfterTest` Method.

Comment: Hi, could you please share all files, driver intializer file, test scripts file and Helper file?